# Need advice on simple audio mixer and setup for novice sitar player to play along with masters recorded audio?

Tags: homerecording, mixer, performance-practice, sitar

Currently the person plays the recorded audio on her laptop and practices along with it, the issue is background noise and other household noise distracting her.

I am not a qualified person, my suggestion to her (Need your advice here) is to use a 2 Ch Analog mixer (some good quality but low cost), where one Ch of the mixer-input is connected to the Laptop audio out, second input Ch of the mixer is connected to the Mic (my guess a Dynamic type ?) that is placed near the Sitar or Piezo pickup. The Audio from both Ch is mixed and routed to a headphone (after splitting the mono to stereo). The musician can then balance the gain as to what suits her.
Is this a correct approach ? .is this how people use ? 
Not sure if I will need any preAmp for Mic or Headphone.
Suggestion on analog mixer and Mic/Piezo ? (low cost)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that idea will work. A piezzo will be better than a mic, because the mic will pick up some of the ambient background noise, which is what you're trying to avoid.The mono/stereo part doesn't have to be a problem, in fact it could be used so that sitar is panned one way, backing track the other.

Recommendations for equipment are out of bounds here, but there are plenty of small 2,3 and 4 channel mixers available. The wiring is pretty straightforward - cable from laptop to mixer, piezzo to mixer, and a decent set of over-ear cans which will cut out extraneous noises.

Answer (score -1):

There are lots of 1- or 2-channel sound cards particularly on the used market that have a physical "monitor mix" dial.  Some of them also provide phantom power to better microphones, and they usually have a headphone output.  If you hook them up to a computer, microphone and headphone, you have all of the necessary equipment for monitoring your own output in connection with prerecorded material, and when you eventually want to record it, you don't need to buy anything extra.

Bonus if they have a mono/stereo switch so that you can work with a single microphone and hear it on both channels.  Alternatively, insert points can be used for getting a mono signal to both outputs: in this case you need a custom TRS (tip ring shield) connector cable wiring T+R on the insert connector of the active microphone (send&return) to R on the passive channel (just return).